# Powershell - create custom windows service to simulate

Tags: powershell

In order to simulate the following code, My question is : I want to create fake delayed windows service called DelayedService with powershell. So I don't want it to go into running state immediately.

Here is my script :

```
$ServiceName = 'DelayedService' # obviously to test...
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
$TimeOut = 20
$count = 0
Start-Service $ServiceName

:SrvCheck while ( $arrService.Status -ne 'Running' )
{
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running' -or $Count -ge $timeout)
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
        Break SrvCheck
    }
    write-host "Waiting for service start, Current Status $($arrService.status) ..."
    Start-Sleep -seconds 3
    ++$count
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This question seems to be incomplete: I cannot understand from the title what are you trying to simulate, nor I can understand what your blocking point is by reading the question. Could you have a look?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://blog.iisreset.me/simulating-faulty-windows-services/)

Comment: Wow thanks for your help @MathiasR.Jessen